# Trouble with animation nodes and objects appearing to be linked when they're not

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, baking, linked-data

I have this animation of some gears turning. It looks fine in the viewport, everything moves correctly, but when I render the animation the gears aren't turning or they're glitching. I tried to solve this by baking to keyframes. However when I do this it messes up the rotation of my gears. Whats even weirder is that is also messes up the rotation of gears that aren't even in the same node tree. Ive cleared all parents and object data, but the problem persists.

[image: how it should look]

[image: After Baking]

What's also strange is my Drive gear obviously has some rotation keyframes to drive the rest of the gears, but some of the other gears have also inherited those same keyframes, and when I delete them from those other gears, they also get deleted from the drive gear. Is there some kind of link other than data or parenting that I might be missing? Please help

Also, Happy to share my blend file but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You shouldn't render an animation directly from the render button when using animation nodes, it is know to malfunction. Instead you can use the text editor to write a script : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1200 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydAmFR2wN9w

Comment: Great i'll give this a go, thank you!